# Inputbox is not accepting double number VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a declaration like `number= InputBox("Number for:", "Number:")`, number is declared as `Dim number As Double` but when I enter a double number, for example *5.4*, into the Inputbox and transmit it into a cell, the cell shows me *54*, it deletes the point.

How can I fix this?

THX

Comment: Try `number = CDbl(InputBox("Number for:", "Number:"))`, may be your system treating `.` as thousands separator?

Comment: I tried it and it does not work :( @PatricK

Comment: InputBox returns a String, please try in separate Sub to test if the decimal is removed somehow. `Sub IB_Test() : Debug.Print """" & InputBox("Num: ","Number:") & """" : End Sub` run and observe the Immediate window.

Comment: @PatricK, I don't see a change :/. Can I use a Parse Function??

Comment: @flowers1234 what language version of Excel you have ? what are your defualt settings for system seperators, such as Decimal seperator and Thoussand seperator ?

Comment: Hinted from Shai Rado. Other things you might want to check are: `Application.ThousandsSeparator`, `Application.UseSystemSeparators`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to detect which settings your Excel uses for the ***Decimal seperator***, try the code below:

```
MsgBox "Excel uses " & Chr(34) & Application.DecimalSeparator & Chr(34) & " as a decimal seperator"
```

if you want to change it to `.`, then use the line below:

```
Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Will the `Application.DecimalSeparator` setting persist through sessions (i.e. the next time you open Excel). And what about if you have other Workbooks open at the same time?

Comment: @Noceo you can modify it when closing the `Sub` or on `Workbook_Close` event if you don;t want it to change the settings for other files

Comment: @ShaiRado , do I have to insert it in my code `Application.DecimalSeparator = "."` . I really don't understand that is, I am confused.

Comment: @flowers1234 try add it in the start of your code, see what the message box comes up with first, and then modiy it, see if it changes the output of your code

Comment: at the start of the code that means before _private sub worksheet_.. or after dim variables?

Comment: @flowers1234 after you `Dim` your variables

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, VBA is horrible at handling differences in decimal seprators. In your case, you should probably use a comma (`,`), instead of a punctuation/dot (`.`).

**Edit:** Using the `Application.DecimalSeparator` method, it now works regardless of regional settings. Be aware though, it seems to cause some issues if you change the comma separator settings for Excel (it seems that VBA somewhat ignores this setting). If you do not change that however, the example should work in all other cas

```
Sub GetNumberFromInputBox()
    Dim val As String
    Dim num As Double

    'Get input
    val = InputBox("Number for:", "Number:")

    Debug.Print Application.DecimalSeparator

    If IsNumeric(val) Then
        'Try to convert to double as usual
        num = CDbl(val)

        'If the dot is removed automatically, then
        'you will se a difference in the length. In
        'those cases, replace the dot with a comma,
        'before converting to double
        If Len(val) <> Len(num) Then
            If Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then
                num = CDbl(Replace(val, ".", ","))
            Else
                num = CDbl(Replace(val, ",", "."))
            End If
        End If

        'Pring the number
        Debug.Print "You selected number: " & num

    Else
        'If its not a number at all, throw an error
        Debug.Print "You typed " & val & ", which is not a number"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: do I need this line? `If Len(val) <> Len(num) Then`

Comment: Either that, or some other way of testing, if VBA messed up your input. If you type `5.4`, and VBA converts it to `54`, then you will get a difference in length (3 and 2 characters respectively). This difference is the trigger for the `replace()` function, which converts your dot to a comma, before continuing.

Comment: When I execute my code including your code and set a breakpoint at this line `If Len(val) <> Len(num) Then
            num = CDbl(Replace(val, ".", ","))
        End If
` in num I get the value 54. I enter a 5.4 in the Inputbox and it still returns 54

Comment: Oh it works! but now in the cell number is 5,4 I want to have 5.4 I need a point :-D. Is there something wrong with the replace method? @Noceo

Comment: That depends on your system configuration. If the system wants to use comma as a seperator, then that is what it will use in the cell. There are many ways to fix/change this. One method is to change the decimal seperator for you Excel configuration: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e

Comment: that works fine thx @Noceo. But this sheet, I am working onto has to work for a lot of people. Can I use this option directly in my code?

Comment: I have edited the code, so it now should work despite of regional settings (unless Excel settings differ from system settings).

Comment: IT WORKS. Thanks !!